# how to decode unicode characters in php

Tags: php, unicode

I am trying to pull data from another site and i am getting unicode characters in my result like this

> Amazon RDS â€“ The Beginnerâ€™s Guide

how can i decode it in php?
Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Those are not "unicode characters" - Those are artefacts of messed-up character encoding. In this case, the most likely explanation is that you are interpreting `utf-8` data as `windows-1252`. This may happen if you take a `utf-8` encoded string and display it in a shell on windows. Or if you display it on a web page, sending a `Content-Type` header with `charset=windows-1252`. Just educated guesses of course, there are numerous ways this could happen.

The solution to your problem is to treat the data as `utf-8`.